# function call on update of component in jsf

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a Treenode inside a form

```
<h:form id="form">
 <p:panel styleClass="gridTree" id="gridTree" style="overflow:auto">
  <p:tree value="#{permissionsBean.root}" var="node" dynamic="true" cache="true" id="permissionTree" >  
   <p:treeNode>
    <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>  
   </p:treeNode>
  </p:tree> 
 </p:panel>
```

To fix the height of the tree and add a scroll bar for the height i am changing the height in a script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        $('.gridTree').css('height',windowHeight-220+'px');
        $(window).resize(function () {
            windowHeight = $(window).height();
            $('.gridTree').css('height',windowHeight-220+'px');
        });
    });
```

Now I am updating the form from the change event of a select one menu `update="@form"` .This will remove the height which was set in the **document.ready** function. So how can call a javascript function that will set the height of tree when the component is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know it is correct or not but if I use the 'onchange' attribute of ui component in JSF to call my resize function worked. I tried with the jQuery change function but it did not work.

```
         <p:selectOneMenu id="categoryName" value="#{permissionsBean.permissions.category}"  >
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="0" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{permissionsBean.permission}" var="perm" itemLabel="#{perm.category}" itemValue="#{perm.category}"/>
                <p:ajax event="change" update="msgs picklist @form"   listener="#{permissionsBean.handleCategoryChange}" oncomplete="resizeComp();"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with jquery forms events.

```
$("select,input,textarea").change(function()
{
//call your resize function
}
```